# Solver causes error "Excel has stopped working"

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use the Excel-Solver-Add-In to solve the following simple calculation:

```
        1               2          
   A Revenue       Variable of solver goes in here          
   B Costs         A fix rate of -3000 goes in here
   C Result        Result of A2+B2 is shown here
   D Target        Result of A2+B2 should be 5000 by changing value in A2
```

*I know I could also solve this by the goalseek function but this is just a simple example to explain you my issue and I will need the solver later in a much more complex calculation.*

I have installed the Excel Solver Add-In on four computers. All of them using Excel 2010. On three of them it works without any issue. However, on the last one I get the message "Excel has stopped working" once I click on the "Solve" Button within the Solver menu. It seems that the solver does not even start calculating. I have checked through all options in Excel and they are equal on each computer. Each file is set on "Automatic Calculation".

Do you have any idea what could be the reason why excel breaks down when using the solver even for a simple problem as above?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This really isn't a programming question. You could delete the question here and ask it on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Did you try repairing Excel on that machine? If it's working everywhere else, that could be it.